# How to open exactly Play Store with deep link?

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking

Some users have installed third party app stores that handle links of `Google Play` by default.
My apps are published only on Play.

Normally I would do this:

```
intent://details?id=X&url=Y&referrer=Z#Intent;scheme=market;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;package=com.android.vending;end";
```

Is it possible to open specifically Google Play if the app was not installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below reference code (replace with your app url)

```
    protected void startPlayStoreActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.hardik.passkey"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent); 
    }
```